# error: server did not accept client registration 68

Tags: iphone, core-location, ios-4.2

I am trying to build and run the WhereamI.app example of the Big Nerd Ranch book: iOS Programming, chapter4.

Compiling works just fine and it runs but the output to console is: server did not accept client registration 68, instead of providing the current GPS position and altitude.

I am runing Xcode 4.1 on OS X Lion with the 4.3 SDK.

There is nothing fancy at all in the code. JUst and instance of Corelocation manager and a simple delegation to WhereAmI.app

Any clues?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same problem. Apparently it's a bug in Xcode 4.1. There's some code on their forum you can add that fixes it:

http://forums.bignerdranch.com/viewtopic.php?f=79&t=2069

Comment: This isn't a fix, but it's a way around the issue.

Comment: Hey guys, I also got one issue with Xcode 4.1 and iOS SDK 4.3 Lion 10.7.1. Please see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670229/exe-bad-access-in-line-14-in-main-m-after-i-type-randomly-when-program-launches. I think its bug with xcode 4.1

Answer (score 2):

Like Brian Liang, I don't think the code offered in the big nerd ranch forums is a fix, per se, because if you use that code, you eliminate not only the application crash "server did not accept client registration 68", you also render the application useless, because the workaround overrides the method that a delegate for CLLocationManager would use to be aware of location updates; overrides it in a way that basically says always update the location to lat:42, long:-50.  So the forum code snippet mentioned here does eliminate the application crash, but it makes all location updates amount to the same coordinates, so you really can't use the application anymore.  Not a fix in any grander sense of the word.  Kind of let down really. Maybe this is just a simulator problem and not an issue on an actual phone?

Comment: Also, if you use the forum hack, update the lat and long to match the front door of apple headquarters so when you place your first annotation it shows up on the screen so you see it is working.  I used initWithLatitude:37.33165 longitude:-122.03075 and when I hit return for the first annotation a red pin pops up right next to the blue blinking apple headquarters location. Then also, if you scroll away from apple headquarters and place another pin, the map will center you back near apple headquarters, so you can see the relocation feature in action too.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Just updated to the latest version of xcode (4.2.1 as of writing) and used the iOS 5.0 SDK instead of 4.3, it works fine now.

Comment: I can repeat this success.  I get the "did not accept client registration" error in the 4.3 simulator, and the 5.0 simulator runs fine.