# viewDidAppear being called before WebService connection methods

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services, connection, viewdidappear

ViewDidAppear method I put breakpoint in the last step of the operation, but the breakpoint viewDidAppear method of putting at first, trying to run it directly.
Are emerging in connection using WebService. Be the first breakpoint while running webservice connections, calling the latest viewDidAppear. However, prior to providing breakpoint viewDidAppear when calling WebService connection, and this causes the value NULL to return.
In short, I would like to be called viewDidAppear method, after obtaining all the webservice connections. Breakpoint when it's like this, but when I want to work in the same way.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[self LabelYukle];
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
if(theConnection)
    [webData setLength:0];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`viewDidAppear` is called by iOS system on its own just before view is going to be appeared.
If you want to perform some functions after `didReceiveResponse` method, there is a method in `NSURLConnectionDelegate` that can help you.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

This method is used when a connection has finished loading successfully and you can write the functions you want to perform after `didRecieveRespose` here in this method.

You can [read more](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/connectionDidFinishLoading%3a) about `NSURLConnectionDelegateProtocol` methods here.

Comment: Puneet, I have another question, can provide multiple web service connection can happen in a certain order? Control over the connection NSURLConnection are we able to?

Comment: You can create multiple NSURLConnection objects. But to maintain a certain order you need to try different things as it is asynchronous in nature. You can try the solution provided here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062393/how-can-we-handle-multiple-nsurlconnection-in-iphone-xcode